# Different Media Converters at both ends for Modbus Communication

Tags: fiber

I am trying to establish Modbus TCP/IP communication. Modbus Master and slave are around 500 mtr away from each other. We are using FO to Copper converter at both ends. Modbus slave end is having Siemens X308-2LH converter and Modbus Master is having Hirschmann 1TX\1FX-SM converter. In this case I am not able to establish communication but if I use Siemens X308-2LH converter at both end communication is estalished. Could anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

As you said the devices are 500m apart, I'll assume that's where all the fiber lives.  As such, you are attempting to plug LH into SM. That doesn't work because they use different frequencies.

See Also: [GigabitEthernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet)